# How to read "next request" correctly?

Tags: pronunciation

How to read "next request" if read fast? Will the `t` and `r` will be put together, so it's sounds like: `nex tre quest`, and the `tre` here is the same as in `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, with my American accent, my pronunciation would be `nex re quest`.  This doesn't really have anything to do with the speed I'm speaking at since I habitually just (mis-)pronounce "next" as `nex` normally.  I will say I'm less likely to use proper pronunciation if I'm speaking quickly.

Even though the "t" and the "r" are closely followed in your text, the `t` and `tr` are very different (the `tr` requires a lot more mouth movement).  I'm not likely to accidentally mix those two sounds up, even while speaking rapidly.